# Google Cloud Instance showing SSH instead of RDP (Windows instead of Linux)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Windows Instance running in Google Cloud with two disks (ie boot disk and empty drive).

I manually logged into the machine and copied boot data into empty drive. I removed the boot and tried to spin up the VM with the empty drive and it was successful.

However, instead of showing RDP connect button now it is showing SSH. Any idea on why this is happening or how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Windows are you installing?

Some new versions of Windows Server like "Core" versions only have access by SSH, the procedure that you have performed seems a little bit strange.

My suggestion is to redeploy your VM and check your attached disk looking for everything that is right on the boot disk.

Answer (score 0):

3 years too late, but I encountered a similar issue.
Please check these links out:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/licenses/view-append#console_1
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-custom#guest-os-features

The image associated with disk apparently needs to have the license info (through the --licenses parameter of the `gcloud compute images create` command)
And it might need to have the --guest-os-features parameter tagged as "WINDOWS".

To get the correct license, I looked at an image that worked, and got the EQUIVALENT REST information.